# Awarding the match ball to the hat-trick scorer

Tags: football, history

When/where did the tradition of awarding the match ball to the hat-trick scorer originate?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Believe it was Birmingham City who began this tradition.

Comment: This is a good answer, but there's nothing to indicate they were the first.